# GIF Image Animation using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, image-loading

I just migrate my android application from Glide. But i've problem when trying to play GIF Image. Is it any solution to play GIF image using Picasso? Thank you.

Comment: At present _no_ according to the [project GitHub](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/700) - Consider using an alternative library

Comment: Unfortunately, I have migrated my app to Picasso from Glide to avoid too many methods. Do you have any suggestion about image loader libraries except Glide to easily perform GIF Animation.

Comment: why you didnt use multidex @ikhsan

Answer (score 12):

Piccaso will not support GIF animation, only Glide will support GIF. [image]